# In SharePoint 2007, how can I update a list item based on a question asked when the workflow is manually run?

Tags: 2007, workflow

I need to be able to update a field that is hidden on the edit form.  I'd like to be able to run a manual workflow that asks a simple Yes/No question, then fills in the field accordingly. This seems like it should be very simple! I've looked at 'Collect Data From User', but it seems more geared for an approval workflow.

I'd appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to create an initiation variable.  Then when the workflow is started, the user must provide an answer, and you use that response to update your list item.